# How to map nested JSON with Lombok

Tags: lombok, spring-rest

I have this JSON API response:

```
{
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://xxx/person{?page,size,sort}",
      "templated": true
    }
},
"_embedded": {
"person": [
  {
    "datetimeCreated": "2015-08-27T11:21:34.000+0000",
    "datetimeLastUpdated": "2015-08-27T11:21:34.000+0000",
    "middleName": "Patricia"
  }
]
},
"page": {
  "size": 20,
  "totalElements": 2,
  "totalPages": 1,
  "number": 0
  }
}
```

I have this class to map the response:

```
@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Person {
    private Links _links;
    private Person _embedded;
    private Page page;
}
```

I can map 'page' with Page class:

```
@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Page {
    private Integer size;
    private Integer totalElements;
    private Integer totalPages;
    private Integer number;
}
```

**But, how can I map '_embedded' and '_links'?** If I map _links and _embedded using the same method, the value is null for this fields.

Answer (score 1):

The json is not matching with your data model. Like, you have declared `_embedded` field as the type of `Person`. But `Person` in turn, has fields `_links`, `page` etc.

To me, the correct data model seems to be :

```
  @Data
  @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
  public class Person1 {
    private Links _links;
    private Embedded _embedded;
    private Page page;

  @Data
  @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
  public static class Page {
    private Integer size;
    private Integer totalElements;
    private Integer totalPages;
    private Integer number;
  }

  @Data
  @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
  public class Links {
    private Self self;
  }

  @Data
  @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
  public static class Embedded {
    private List<Person> person;
  }

  @Data
  @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
  public static class Self {
    private String href;
    private boolean templated;
  }

  @Data
  @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
  public static class Person {
    private DateTime datetimeCreated;
    private DateTime datetimeLastUpdated;
    private String middleName;
  }
}
```